# Encontrar el numero total de clicks en un post de facebook API

Tags: api, facebook-api

Necesito saber como conseguir el número total de clicks utilizando la API de facebook en cada uno de los post que tengo.
Antes utilizaba otra tecnología en la que usaba el campo "page_consumptions" pero ahora he de sacarla directamente de la API ... alguien sabe como procede?
Con la ayuda de APi GRAPH he conseguido saca el reactions(que según parece son likes)
`me/posts?fields=name,reactions.summary(true),comments.summary(true)&since=1 september 2022&until=6 september 2022`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si lo conseguiste, pero yo sacaba el dato para ponerlos en una hoja de calculo, usaba collab, primero obtenía los ID´s de las publicaciones y luego sacaba el dato pidiendo los insights de cada post con el parametro "post_clicks_by_type", ya bajado en código solo itero por ID.

```
array_datos = []  # Crear un array vacío para almacenar todos los datos
suma = 0

for seccion in data:
#Se crear un diccionario ya con los elementos que queremos para así no preocuparse del orden de los llamados, ya que algunos requieren acceder con el ID del post
    datos_seccion = {"permalink_url": "-","created_time":"-","message":"-", "reactions":0, "comments":0,"shares":0,"link_click":0,"otros_clicks":0,"views":0,"alcance_organico":0,"alcance_paid":0 }  
    
    if "permalink_url" in seccion:
        datos_seccion["permalink_url"] = seccion["permalink_url"]
    else:
        datos_seccion["permalink_url"] = None
        
    if "created_time" in seccion:
        datos_seccion["created_time"] = seccion["created_time"]
    else:
        datos_seccion["created_time"] = None

    if "message" in seccion:
        datos_seccion["message"] = seccion["message"]
    else:
        datos_seccion["message"] = None

##Hay problemas con los comentarios, no está dando todos los datos en algunos casos, hipotesis: hay un límite por defecto que no se está especificando, se presenta en los post con más de 500 comentarios. 
    if "comments" in seccion:
      total_comments = 0
      for comment in seccion['comments']['data']:
        total_comments += comment['comment_count']
      datos_seccion["comments"] = total_comments + len(seccion["comments"]["data"])
    
    else:
      datos_seccion["comments"] = 0

    if "shares" in seccion and "count" in seccion["shares"]:
      datos_seccion["shares"] = seccion["shares"]["count"]
    else:
      datos_seccion["shares"] = 0 

    if "id" in seccion:
      urlPost="https://graph.facebook.com/" + seccion["id"] + "/insights?metric=post_reactions_by_type_total,post_clicks_by_type,post_video_views,post_impressions_organic_unique,post_impressions_paid_unique&since=" + fecha_de_inicio + "&until=" + fecha_de_final + "&access_token=" + access_token
      output = requests.get(urlPost).json()
      datosID = output["data"]
    
      for valor in datosID[0]["values"][0]["value"].values():
        suma += valor


      if "link clicks" in datosID[1]["values"][0]["value"]:
        datos_seccion["link_click"] = datosID[1]["values"][0]["value"]["link clicks"]
      else:
        datos_seccion["link_click"] = 0

      if "other clicks" in datosID[1]["values"][0]["value"]:
        datos_seccion["otros_clicks"] = datosID[1]["values"][0]["value"]["other clicks"]
      else:
        datos_seccion["otros_clicks"] = 0


      datos_seccion["views"] = datosID[2]["values"][0]["value"]

      datos_seccion["alcance_organico"] = datosID[3]["values"][0]["value"]
      
      datos_seccion["alcance_paid"] = datosID[4]["values"][0]["value"] 

      datos_seccion["reactions"] = suma
      suma=0
       
    else:
      datos_seccion["id"] = None

    # Agregar el diccionario de datos_seccion al array array_datos
    array_datos.append(datos_seccion)


print(array_datos)
```

En post_clicks_by_type te da los clicks al link y los otros clicks, pero si no hay simplemente no te genera la sección en el JSON, por eso tuve que crear unos condicionales para lidear con esa situación de esas métricas.

```
  if "link clicks" in datosID[1]["values"][0]["value"]:
    datos_seccion["link_click"] = datosID[1]["values"][0]["value"]["link clicks"]
  else:
    datos_seccion["link_click"] = 0

  if "other clicks" in datosID[1]["values"][0]["value"]:
    datos_seccion["otros_clicks"] = datosID[1]["values"][0]["value"]["other clicks"]
  else:
    datos_seccion["otros_clicks"] = 0
```